# Windows can't start booting without the CD

Tags: windows-7, boot

What is the reason that my Windows can't start up without the OS CD after I switch on my computer if there is any settings problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your boot loader seams to be missing. Boot into the [Windows 7 Recovery options](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/start-the-windows-7-recovery-environment/) and select **startup repair**

[image]

> **Startup Repair**
>
> Startup Repair is an automated procedure that attempts to fix common issues with Windows that may not allow it to startup properly.
>   This tool will automatically start when Windows is unable to start
>   after a few attempts.